# How to download the wikipedia articles that are listed in PetScan tool?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I had shortlisted a list of Wikipedia articles using the Petscan tool. Below is the link https://petscan.wmflabs.org/

I have used "Diseases & disorders" category from wikipedia with a depth value of 2. Approx 10000 articles were listed in the results.

My question is how do I download the articles to my computer. I am new to these things so need help.

Comment: The options for that are under the Output tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out with the help of comment from [@Tgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323407/tgr) above. I navigated to output options and found a bunch of formats for exporting the file. They are as follows,

1. HTML
2. JSON
3. CSV
4. Pagepile

Simply choose the option and get the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Just navigate to **Output** tab, and choose the format you need to export to, then click **Do it**. After that, the data will be downloaded to your PC.